# Loop through nested array wordpress json api

Tags: arrays, json, wordpress, nested, each

Hi i want to loop through comments in a json file (wordpress json api) the problem is i want to use the each function to display all the comments. How i loop with the each function true a nested array i can't find the solution. now i use the following code, but thats only showing the first item

`var html2 ='<p>'+ data.post.comments[0]["name"] +'<br><p>'+ data.post.comments[0]["content"] +'</p>'; 
$( ".content>.comments" ).append(html2);`

the json file:
http://indinxperlo.nl/api/get_post/?post_id=399

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
var html = [];
$.each(data.post.comments, function(key,val){
   html.push('<p>'+val["name"]+'</p>');
});
$(".content>.comments").append(html.join(''));
```

If you want to control number of max comments shown do this:

```
var html = [];
var count = 0;
$.each(data.post.comments, function(key,val){
   html.push('<p>'+val["name"]+'</p>');
   if (count == 5) {return false;}
   count++;
});
$(".content>.comments").append(html.join(''));
```

Comment: Thanx salivan, i tried many ways but didn't know that the push and join are the answer. I tried also a for loop so you can set a maximum of showing comments but i had also no luck with that.

Comment: @heidemanmedia p.s. you can set max showing comments with each too. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: thanx thats a nice extra functionality!